# Riesz representation theorem: show isometry

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, alternative-proof, isometry, riesz-representation-theorem

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space and $J:X\rightarrow X',J(X):=(\cdot,x)$ where $X'$ is the dual space of $X$.

I have to show that $\|J(x)\|_{\sup}=\|x\|$.

''$\leq$'' is clear by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

For ''$\geq$'' I somehow have to use $|J(x)(x)|=|(x,x)|=\|x\|^{2}$ but I don't see how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x \neq 0$, $|J(x) (\frac x {\|x\|})|=\|x\|$ so $\|J(x)\| \geq \|x\|$.

Comment: But why is the $x$ in $J(x)$ the same as in the argument (normed) ?

Comment: I am confused how this shows that $||J(x)|| \geq ||x||$?

Comment: @skim The supremum of  set $A$ of real numbers is greater than or equal to $a$ for any element $a $ of $A$.